# Display process output incrementally using Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, output

I'm trying to run "docker-compose pull" from inside a Python automation script and to incrementally display the same output that Docker command would print if it was run directly from the shell. This command prints a line for each Docker image found in the system, incrementally updates each line with the Docker image's download progress (a percentage) and replaces this percentage with a "done" when the download has completed. I first tried getting the command output with subprocess.poll() and (blocking) readline() calls:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

def run(command, shell=False):

    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=shell)
    while True:
        # print one output line  
        output_line = p.stdout.readline().decode('utf8')
        error_output_line = p.stderr.readline().decode('utf8')
        if output_line:
            print(output_line.strip())
        if error_output_line:
            print(error_output_line.strip())

        # check if process finished
        return_code = p.poll()
        if return_code is not None and output_line == '' and error_output_line == '':
            break

    if return_code > 0:
        print("%s failed, error code %d" % (command, return_code))


run("docker-compose pull")
```

The code gets stuck in the first (blocking) readline() call. Then I tried to do the same without blocking:

```
import select
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys
import time

def run(command, shell=False):

    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=shell)
    io_poller = select.poll()
    io_poller.register(p.stdout.fileno(), select.POLLIN)
    io_poller.register(p.stderr.fileno(), select.POLLIN)
    while True:
        # poll IO for output
        io_events_list = []
        while not io_events_list:
            time.sleep(1)
            io_events_list = io_poller.poll(0)

        # print new output
        for event in io_events_list:
            # must be tested because non-registered events (eg POLLHUP) can also be returned
            if event[1] & select.POLLIN: 
                if event[0] == p.stdout.fileno():
                   output_str = p.stdout.read(1).decode('utf8')
                   print(output_str, end="") 
                if event[0] == p.stderr.fileno():
                   error_output_str = p.stderr.read(1).decode('utf8')
                   print(error_output_str, end="")

        # check if process finished
        # when subprocess finishes, iopoller.poll(0) returns a list with 2 select.POLLHUP events
        # (one for stdout, one for stderr) and does not enter in the inner loop
        return_code = p.poll()
        if return_code is not None:
            break

    if return_code > 0:
        print("%s failed, error code %d" % (command, return_code))


run("docker-compose pull")
```

This works, but only the final lines (with "done" at the end) are printed to the screen, when all Docker images downloads have been completed.

Both methods work fine with a command with simpler output such as "ls". Maybe the problem is related with how this Docker command prints incrementally to screen, overwriting already written lines ? Is there a safe way to incrementally show the exact output of a command in the command line when running it via a Python script?

EDIT: 2nd code block was corrected

Answer (score 1):

1. Always openSTDIN as a pipe, and if you are not using it, close it immediately.
2. p.stdout.read() will block until the pipe is closed, so your polling code does nothing useful here. It needs modifications.
3. I suggest not to use shell=True
4. Instead of *.readline(), try with *.read(1) and wait for "\n"

Of course you can do what you want in Python, the question is how. Because, a child process might have different ideas about how its output should look like, that's when trouble starts. E.g. the process might want explicitly a terminal at the other end, not your process. Or a lot of such simple nonsense. Also, a buffering may also cause problems. You can try starting Python in unbuffered mode to check. (/usr/bin/python -U)

If nothing works, then use pexpect automation library instead of subprocess.

Comment: (2) was the source of the problem in my 2nd code block, I didn't know read() blocked until the pipe was closed. Thanks! Btw my 1st code block also didn't work because (1) I was running p.stdout.readline() and p.stderr.readline() sequentially and code got stuck in the one of them because processes only writes to one of them when there is no error and (2) I was using readline() instead of read() and "docker-compose pull" only writes newlines for the initial display, subsequent lines updates do not have a newline and didnt show up. Also, docker-compose strangely prints to stderr instead of stdout

Comment: It is not strange for a process to write to stderr. stderr is not dedicated to errors only. Imagine you have a process who's result you wish to pipe somewhere, e.g. a file, but you also want to be able to watch the progress. You write the progress to stderr and redirect the stdout to the pipe. One example is ffmpeg when audio/video stream is piped.

Comment: I'm sorry for not noticing that you tried to read both err and out or I would pointed it out. You can solve this problem by starting threads. One reads stderr and another stdout and results are put in a queue. You use a lock to properly sync the threads. Main thread monitors the queue and decides what to do with the results. e.g. for main thread --> while p.poll()==None: res = some_queue.pop(0); if res[0]=="stderr": print res[1]; p.stdout.close(); p.stderr.close(); break ... Monitor threads must manage IOErrors caused by forcing pipes to close. You can also use p.terminate()

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, based on the first code block of my question:

```
def run(command,shell=False):

    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=shell)
    while True:
        # read one char at a time  
        output_line = p.stderr.read(1).decode("utf8")
        if output_line != "":
            print(output_line,end="")
        else:
            # check if process finished
            return_code = p.poll()
            if return_code is not None:
                if return_code > 0:
                    raise Exception("Command %s failed" % command)
                break

    return return_code
```

Notice that docker-compose uses stderr to print its progress instead of stdout. @Dalen has explained that some applications do it when they want that their results are pipeable somewhere, for instance a file, but also want to be able to show their progress.

Comment: Note that *.decode(...) does nothing here. You are getting one char at a time, but UTF-8 characters outside ANSII/ASCII range are composed from 2 bytes, so, *.decode() has nothing to decode with only one byte available. And as I explained in another comment, nothing is odd with printing status to stderr.

Comment: I tried removing the decode() call and I got a lot of bytes instead of chars (using Python 2). I didn't know that it was usual to use stderr to print status. It seems a little hackish to me, but I understand its usefulness. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It's unusual just because there is usually no need of this, as you correctly put it, hackish solution. Historically stderr was meant for errors, but simply practice needs it for more. There are other solutions possible, but when you have tasks that take long and piping is supported, then expect all status on stderr and stdout for results only. It is the least hackish solution among some really crazy possibilities. And, also, if you ever find yourself needing this kind of output, this is the easiest way. Other hacks are ugly and dirty. :D

Comment: @AlanEvangelista `if return_code > 0` should instead be `if return_code < 0`